# i need the buttons to be aligned side to side not top and botton

Tags: html, css

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div align="center">
    <form method="link" action="file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/about%20samoyeds">
      <input type="submit" value="About Samoyeds" style="width:120px; height:40px; background-color: darkwhite; border-color: black; ">
    </form>
    <form method="link" action="http://www.hillspet.com/en/us/dog-breeds/samoyed">
      <input type="submit" value="History of Samoyeds" style="width:150px; height:40px; background-color: darkwhite; border-color: black; ">
    </form>
    <form method="link" action="file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/dealers%20of%20samoyeds">
      <input type="submit" value="Samoyed Dealers" style="width:130px; height:40px; background-color: darkwhite; border-color: black; ">
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[pic of what code comes out as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSVut.jpg)

this is the code I have a lot more I used but that has nothing to do with this so it's not in there I have a problem with that code

Answer (score 3):

Make the `form` elements `display: inline-block;`

BTW, the `align` attribute is deprecated. Use CSS to align/center things instead.

```css
.wrap {
  text-align: center;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <form method="link" action="file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/about%20samoyeds">
      <input type="submit" value="About Samoyeds" style="width:120px; height:40px; background-color: darkwhite; border-color: black; ">
    </form>
    <form method="link" action="http://www.hillspet.com/en/us/dog-breeds/samoyed">
      <input type="submit" value="History of Samoyeds" style="width:150px; height:40px; background-color: darkwhite; border-color: black; ">
    </form>
    <form method="link" action="file:///C:/Users/David/Desktop/dealers%20of%20samoyeds">
      <input type="submit" value="Samoyed Dealers" style="width:130px; height:40px; background-color: darkwhite; border-color: black; ">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I did what you said but it didn't work it made the buttons line up vertically the same way only on the left side of the screen, not the center